# webpage content not updated through json function(data)

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to update a webpage on the fly after inserting some data in the db and returning a json object to no avail.

Let's say I have

```
<div id="try1"> try(<span id="votes1">0</span>)</div>
```

When loeaded the page displays the current number of votes, (0) at the moment.

then I have a button

```
<button  onclick="vote(1);">+</button>
```

that calls this function:

```
function vote(votes_id)
{

  var div = 'try' +votes_id;

  var url = 'vote.php?id=' +votes_id;

  var destination = '#votes' +votes_id;

  $.getJSON( url, function(data) {
    $(destination).html (data.votes);

  }); 

}
```

my vote.php returns this json or after correctly updating the db or, at least that is what I think

```
{"votes":"1"}
```

However my webpage doesn't get updated from 0 to 1,

I use `$data = json_encode($data);`

the result of which as var_dump is:

```
string '{"votes":"1"}'
```

and

```
{"votes":"1"}
```

as echo $data.

What am I possibly missing?

Comment: On firefox, install Firebug if you haven't already and check the Net Tab. Can you see the ajax request? What is the Answer? Is it the correct data? Also, add some alert() in your javascript, both before sending the request (to confirm that you reach that point) and inside the callback function (to confirm that the callback is called).

Comment: Can you paste what `console.log(data);` returns in your ajax callback?

Comment: when you say 'at least that is what I think', Is your db definitely getting updated ? instead of `$(destination).html (data.votes);` do an alert and see what comes up to make sure everything is good before continuing `alert(data.votes);` and why the divs var ? are you supposed to be using that in the url var ?

Comment: i added console.log(data) at the end of that script. I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined vote_designer.js:15
vote vote.js:15
onclick

Comment: @billy because I have many divs in the same page created by a loop that I need to update in case of click so I need different id identifiers. Yes the DB is being updated.

Comment: but you don't use the var div anywhere, that's why i thought you meant to add it to the url var. as data isn't defined there is a problem somewhere else in your script, not the bit you posted.

Comment: @Billy, true I removed it, it was from a previous version.

Comment: So the DB gets updated, the alerts pre and post appear, this is the result of the call: send  @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax  @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
m.(anonymous function)  @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
m.extend.getJSON  @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
vote  @ vote.js:12
onclick

Comment: so if you do `alert(data.votes);` before the update to destination html you get an alert with the correct data, yes ?? try taking the space out after html at `$(destination).html (data.votes);`, probably won't make a difference but you never know.

Comment: nothing appears with alert(data.votes); before update. How am I supposed to define data anyway? and where? I tried to define it in the php file with a script to no avail

Comment: well, I don't know what happened as I think I didn't change anything and the damn thing started working: my php part now is: $data = json_encode($data); echo $data; and the javascript is exactly the same without that div part

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are putting he success callback in the wrong place.

Use:

```
function vote(votes_id)
{

  var div = 'try' +votes_id;

  var url = 'vote.php?id=' +votes_id;

  var destination = '#votes' +votes_id;

  $.getJSON( url, {}, function(data) {
    $(destination).html (data.votes);

  }); 

}
```

Comment: PS: The javascript thinks you are trying to SEND data in a variable named data...but since you have not defined a 'data' variable, the error is saying data variable is undefined. By moving the "function(data)" success callback to its correct location, js will know your RECEIVING data in the variable named 'data' and wont throw he error.